# How do I create Conda environment in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I am trying to setup a conda environment in windows command promt so I can create a python discord bot but I get an error, I tried creating the environment in Anaconda prompt and it worked but pycharm didn't recognise it. How do I create the environment in windows promt so it is recognised by pycharm and so that when I import discord, it can be used normally. (Currently says there's no module named discord even though I installed it). I am using this tutorial : [Conda env setup video for discord bot](https:///www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdg39s4HSJQ&t=458s) , around minute 7:05 of the video is when this youtuber starts explaining how to create a conda env and he gets no errors while I do. 
This is the error I get :

> C:\Users\PC>conda create -n bot python=3.6
>
> WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
>   Collecting package metadata: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
>   a support request with your network engineering team.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

I have installed python 3.6.8. which is needed for this to work but the problem seems to be with the windows promt error, 10:40 minute mark of the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdg39s4HSJQ&t=458s) is when he starts setting up a configuration for his project and his environment has a [python symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q7L0.png) but mine has a [conda symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5qPq.png) because I used Anaconda powershell to setup the env which obviously doesn't work. And I tried setting it up in windows promt but I get the error shown above. So how do I fix this?

Comment: is anaconda.com accessible to you on normal browsing?

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) might be of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just needed to put the interpreter as python rather than anaconda.